# calculating the size of structure

Tags: c, struct, padding

I was going through the concept of structure member alignment and structure padding concept when I found that the size of this `struct` ...

```
struct node{
  int b;
  char a;
 };
```

... is 8 bytes (i.e. it contains 3 bytes of padding) whereas the size of this `struct` ...

```
struct node{
  char a;
};
```

... is only 1 byte.  Why is there no padding in the latter?

Comment: Please research C padding rules before posting. If you did please include what you found and why you are still confused.

Comment: Think about arrays, `node[N]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember theses two rules for padding:

1. Padding is only inserted when a structure member is **followed by** a member with a **larger alignment** requirement or at the **end** of the structure.
2. The last member is padded with the number of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member.

Member `a` in second structure is not followed by any member or member with larger alignment and it is also the largest alignment member which means--No Padding.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28928369/2455888) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the link. I didn't know about the second fact. Thanks!!

Comment: What if I say I have a structure whose one member is : int(4 bytes) and another is double, will structure padding occur in this after int? By the rule we know that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of 8(size of double), but even if we don't do any padding, double will be read in 2 cycles. Also, about the array of objects, if the size is 12 Bytes (without padding), next object will be also be read in the minimum number of cycles and also the same with 16 (with padding bytes). Ideone gives 12 as the siz eof such structure while codeblocks, Dev give 16. Which is correct?

Comment: I do not understand your question?

Comment: Assume we have a structure which has two members, i.e. struct { int a; double b;} What will be the size of structure 12 or 16? Ideone gives 12 and codeblocks,Dev give 16.

Comment: See this: http://ideone.com/CTv8bs , it gives 12 while the same on CodeBlocks and Dev gives 16.

Comment: What rule is saying is correct. Ignore ideone result. It may used `-fpack-struct` option for structure packing (I am not sure about).

Comment: I didn't use any option, I was actually thinking about why the size cannot be 12. Lets say, the size is 12. How it is getting allocated is: first 4 bytes for integer and next 8 bytes for double. We introduce padding bytes for minimizing the number of memory read cycles if I am not wrong. With the size as 12, the read cycles required by int is 1 and for double it's 2.

Comment: Also, thinking about the array of objects. Lets say first object was allocated at 0x0000, double will then be at 4 bytes from this. Next object will be at increment of 12 bytes( int of sec object) and 16 bytes (double of sec object). So, there still isn't any ambiguity about the memory read cycles for array of objects. So, what's the problem with size being 12 bytes even!!

Comment: There is no problem with except that ideone may have some problem. Do not waste your time in such things. What answer is saying is correct.

Answer (score 2):

## [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Described wonderfully [here](http://www.c-faq.com/struct/align.html).

Suppose you have this structure:

```
struct  {
    char a[3];
    short int b;
    long int c;
    char d[3];
    };
```

Now, you might think that it ought to be possible to pack this structure into memory like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   b   |           c           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   c   |           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But it's much, much easier on the processor if the compiler arranges it like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

In the ''packed'' version, notice how it's at least a little bit hard for you and me to see how the b and c fields wrap around? In a nutshell, it's hard for the processor, too. Therefore, most compilers will ''pad'' the structure (as if with extra, invisible fields) like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           | pad1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |     pad2      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           | pad3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

<sup>This post explained how padding is done, not why it is done. Please refer haccks' answer for why it is done.</sup>

Comment: Actually the link you provided explains why padding is needed, not when and how it is done.

Comment: I'm too lazy to rewrite it, so I just added a P.S. to the post.

Answer (score 1):

The padding and alignment of members of a `struct` are completely at the discretion of the compiler, except that there cannot be any padding before the first member.  With that said, compilers normally choose padding to serve alignment purposes, so that, in particular,

1. it is possible for all the members of the same struct to be optimally aligned at the same time, and
2. in an array of `structs`, if the members of the first array element are aligned optimally then so will be the members of all the others.

Subject to those and similar requirements, compilers typically choose the least amount of padding necessary (ideally no padding at all).  If different member types have different alignment requirements, then the above considerations require `struct` representations to be padded to a multiple of the size of the member with the most stringent alignment requirement.  They may also require padding between members, depending on the types of the members and their order.