# Why does sizeof structure wrong?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
typedef struct{
    int tournamentNo;
    char tournamentName[61];
    char toutnamentDate[15];
    char tournamentCity[21];
}Tournament;
```

printf(" : %d ", sizeof(Tournament));

result: 104

actual: 61+15+21 + 4 = 101

```
typedef struct{
    int tournamentNo;
    char tournamentName[20];
    char toutnamentDate[15];
    char tournamentCity[21];
}Tournament;
```

printf(" : %d ", sizeof(Tournament));

result: 60

actual: 20 + 15 +21 +4  = 60

Why different this ?

Comment: You have 3 additional padding bytes at the end of the struct, to maintain alignment (4 bytes in this case, presumably you're on a 32 bit OS).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28928283/2455888